# Question on calculating the joint PDF by differentiating the joint CDF

Tags: probability

Apologies in advance to the community as I haven't yet learned how to use MathJax and so have to attach my question and attempt as images. I'm stuck on this question where it asks me to derive the joint PDF and I attempt to get it by first obtaining the joint CDF and then differentiating, as my result is different from the answer provided on the solution manual, so I would be grateful if someone can kindly point out for me which step I got wrong. In particular I'm interested in whether I applied the Product Rule & Chain Rule incorrectly. I am aware that this question can be solved by transforming the variables involved, but I'm curious to how I can arrive at the same result by starting with the joint CDF.[This is the Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnjGa.png)[And this is how I'm attempting to tackle the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qmnA.png). Would appreciate any feedback from the community. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: $X+Y \leq t,  X \leq x$ is not equivalent to $Y\leq t-x, X\leq x$. You canot split $P(X+Y \leq t,  X \leq x)$  as  a product of two probabilties.

Comment: Thank you for replying. May I confirm that this operation is not allowed even when these two random variables are independent from each other (which in this case is true)?

Comment: It is not valid even with independence.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!